# Is it possible for _M_X64 to be unset on a x64 processor?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Visual Studio Compilers(2005 through 2008) defines four macros for x86/x64 bit environment. Refer [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)

- _M_X64 Defined for x64 processors.
- _M_IX86 Defined for x86 processors. See the Values for _M_IX86 table below for more information. This is not defined for x64 processors.
- _WIN32 Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.
- _WIN64 Defined for applications for Win64.

Now on a x32 bit machine _M_X64 would never be set. On a 64 bit machine, if you are building on a 32 bit environment _M_X64 would be unset and _M_IX86 would be defined. _WIN32 is always defined irrespective of a 32/64 bit build.

Across all x64 processors, is there special significance of _M_X64? Can there be a scenario when _M_X64 is undefined when target is x64?

Comment: Do these macro depend on the machine the compiler runs? Or does it depend on the target the compiled program will run on? This is important, as I don't understand your statement "Now on a x32 bit machine". IMHO, these macro only depend on the *target*. And you can compile for 64 target on 32 bits system, just as the opposite is true..

Comment: @DidierTrosset: If I am not wrong a 32 bit machine (x32) cannot build programs for 64 bit target, so I believe on such machines _M_X64 will always be undefined.

Comment: @Abhijit: A 32-bit system can build 64-bit code easily. And my 64-bit laptop here can build code for at least six different processor architectures (PPC, PPC64, i386, x86_64, ARMv6, and ARMv7 off the top of my head.) The architecture of the build system has nothing to do with the generated code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now on a x32 bit machine _M_X64 would never be set

That's not how it works.  The compiler you use generates code for a specific target architecture, it doesn't care about **your** machine.  Generating x64 code on a 32-bit machine is very possible, MSVC includes a cross compiler that can run on a 32-bit operating system and generate code for x64.  And it has a 64-bit compiler that generates x64 code.  The IDE is setup to actually use the cross-compiler, regardless of your OS.

You can see these compilers installed on your machine, the `vc\bin` subdirectory of the VS install directory.  That directory contains a 32-bit compiler that generates x86 code.  The x86_amd64 subdirectory has a 32-bit compiler that generates x64 code.  The amd64 subdirectory has a 64-bit compiler that generates x64 code.  Additional directories may exist there if you have compilers for ARM cores.  Which are always cross-compilers.

The macro names you ask about are predefined macros, the full list [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  The _M_X64 macro is always defined by any of the compilers that generate x64 code.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation. That leaves me to wonder "If its possible on a 64 bit Machine (64 bit processor with 64 bit OS), to target 64 bit processor (_M_X64 is defined) to build a 32 bit build (_WIN64 not defined)

Comment: You simple use the 32-bit compiler to generate x86 code.  _M_X64 will of course not be defined.  It sounds like you are still mixing up the machine that you run the compiler on with the target architecture.  Focus on "it doesn't care about **your** machine".